# Insert .tex file in Lyx with references

Tags: latex, lyx

I wrote a draft of a paper in LaTeX. Now my advisor wants the whole thing in Lyx. Equations and all that import just fine using "File -> Import -> LaTeX (plain)" but the natbib references (e.g. `\citet{nash1950game}`) show us as ERT (evil red text, or LaTeX code in red boxes). Do I have to add all these references manually? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you make an example (in this case it would be a .tex file and a .bib file) and make an enhancement request at http://www.lyx.org/trac . Please select the component "tex2lyx'.